# Do actors performing stunts have to take substance test?

Tags: film-industry, stunts

We all know that some actors are known to abuse alcohol or drugs in their free time. Considering some of them choose to perform certain stunts without a sub, I would imagine they could impose a great amount of danger to themselves as well as participating crew under any sort of influence.

Are they supposed to take any kind of substance test before performing dangerous stunts?

Comment: Given that pretty much every Hollywood actor has free access to a vast array of narcotics, both legal and illegal, my guess is that if you drug-tested every actor on set, they'd **all** fail. Massively. Except Tom Hanks.

Comment: My guess is if you even mentioned it, you'd be gone long before the actor had even got to set. "Don't upset the talent" is the golden rule.

Comment: @Richard: *Especially* Tom Hanks. It's always the nice ones.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the [Safety Digest](http://www.sagaftra.org/files/sag/Digest_Stunt_Safety_Theatrical_Television_8_6_0.pdf) that specifically regulates drug or alcohol use.  However, I'm sure if injury arises from drug or alcohol use, the insurance company is going to argue against payments.  Also, the Stunt Coordinator can pull the plug on any stuntman at any time, so if you show up to work intoxicated it's going to get you pulled from the stunt and most likely damage your reputation.